# How to optimize this?

Tags: java, sqlite, optimization, jdbc

java sqlite insert very slow... 
 my code is this

```
        for(int i = 1 ; i <= list.size(); i++ ) {
        query="INSERT OR REPLACE INTO highErrorProbabillityDB VALUES (?,?);";
        prep = localError.prepareStatement(query);
        prep.setString(1, list.get(i-1).get("ki"));
        prep.setInt(2, Integer.parseInt(list.get(i-1).get("ccolor")));
        prep.executeUpdate();
        }
```

The first column is primary key and On average, it takes time of about one to 150Milliseconds.

how to optimize this code?

Comment: 150ms to do the entire batch?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609637/is-it-possible-to-insert-multiple-rows-at-a-time-in-an-sqlite-database

Comment: do you really need to prepare the statement every time?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you could prepare statement only once:

```
query="INSERT OR REPLACE INTO highErrorProbabillityDB VALUES (?,?);";
prep = localError.prepareStatement(query);
for(int i = 1 ; i <= list.size(); i++ ) {
    prep.setString(1, list.get(i-1).get("ki"));
    prep.setInt(2, Integer.parseInt(list.get(i-1).get("ccolor")));
    prep.executeUpdate();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have SQLite version [3.7.11](http://www.sqlite.org/releaselog/3_7_11.html) or greater then you can do multiple inserts at once like this

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO highErrorProbabillityDB 
VALUES (1,4),
       (2,5),
       (3,6),
       ...
```

That way you only have to execute a single query.